# How to generate a MAP file in visual Studio

Tags: c, visual-studio-2012, map-files

Generaly IDEs has option to generate MAP file which shows the locations of the functions and the variables across the memory and the STACK and RAM usages.
Where in Visual Studio Projects we can generate a MAP file  and get this information.Especially the Stack and RAM  statistics.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you want to take a look at the documentation.

The linker directive which will create a .map file is just,
/MAP[:filename]

and..

filename: A user-specified name for the mapfile. It replaces the default name.

found under https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7xkk3e2.aspx

This linker directive should be what you were looking for :).
Or better to be found under

1. Open the project's Property Pages dialog box. For details, see Setting Visual C++ Project Properties.
2. Click the Linker folder.
3. Click the Debug property page.
4. Modify the Generate Map File property.